# Angular material table sum of array elements

Tags: html, angular

As it is my first post here, I would like to say hello to everybody so...

Hello everybody :)

I have a problem with angular and html and I cant find a way to solve it.
Lets say I have 2 interfaces:

```
export interface Product {
    name?: string;
    price?: number;}

export interface Meal {
    name?: string;
    products?: Array<Product>;}
```

I want to create table like this:

```
meal name | price
pizza     | 10
```

Where 10 is sum of prices of each product in meal.

Now i cannot find a way to sum those prices in html. Is it possible or should I do it in ts file? Or maybe this shoud be done in java backend and asked with rest? Or maybe should I add "totalPrice" to meal class?

This is my table:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> meal name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element.name}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> price </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          //<ng-container *ngFor="let product of element.products">
          //{{product.price}}
          //</ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

In your template:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  {{calculateMealTotal(element.products)}}
</td>
```

And in the component file:

```
calculateMealTotal(products: Product[]): number {
  return products.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.price, 0)
}
```

This will sum up the total value of all of the products.